# Add increment count column in PrimeVue dataTable

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

I am using a primevue basic dataTable that works fine in VUE 3, composition api.  I added a template column that is show to show each row incrementing by 1 and starting with 1.  As you can see from the image below, the numbers are way off.  Any ideas on how to fix?

[image]

Here's the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-datatable-with-column-count-msucft?file=/src/DataTableBasicDemo.vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another property to your `products` array and display it in the table:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <DataTable :value="productsWithRowNumber" responsiveLayout="scroll">
      <Column field="rowNumber" header="#"></Column>
      <Column field="code" header="Code"></Column>
      <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
      <Column field="category" header="Category"></Column>
      <Column field="quantity" header="Quantity"></Column>
    </DataTable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, onMounted } from "vue";
import ProductService from "./service/ProductService";

export default {
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      productService.value
        .getProductsSmall()
        .then((data) => (products.value = data));
    });

    const products = ref([]);
    const productService = ref(new ProductService());

    const productsWithRowNumber = computed(() =>
      products.value.map((p, i) => ({ rowNumber: i + 1, ...p }))
    );

    return { productsWithRowNumber, productService };
  },
};
</script>
```

Be aware though, that this will only work properly if you do not change the sorting of the table.